# How to add a progress bar so the user doesn't hit Cancel in a dialog?

Tags: installshield, installshield-2011

I'm working with Installshield 2011 on a basic MSI project.

The problem I have is that the SetupInitialization dialog is taking about 2 to 3 minutes when performing upgrades. During those minutes the users only see:

**Computing space requirements**

And nothing seems to be happening.

I'd like to add some kind of progress bar so they become aware that something is happening and that they shouldn't hit cancel (We've documented that this steps takes a while, but of course everybody reads the documentation, right?)

I've tried adding an animated GIF file with some kind of progress bar, but seems like GIF files are not permitted in dialogs.

Now I'm exploring the Progress Bar control, but I'm not sure this is the right way to go.

Does anybody know how can I achieve what I need?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not supported by MSI packages.

Do you have custom actions in InstallUISequence? If you do, make sure that you set an [Action Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367516%28VS.85%29.aspx) for them. The initialization dialog should display the action text for all InstallUISequence actions executed before the first modal installation dialog.

If you don't have custom actions, but you have a very large installer, you have limited options.

A solution would be an external UI which can display an indeterminate progress. For example a HTML control. Not sure if InstallShield supports a custom progress bar in HTML, but you can try.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my case I don't have custom actions, it's just a very large installer. I'll try to explore the possibility of an HTML control, but I'm not sure it's possible under InstallShield.

Comment: Cosmin Pirvu, I see you come from Advanced Installer. Are HTML controls something that can be easily achieved with that product?

Comment: It does have HTML host controls and a sample HTML theme, but you still need to create your own HTML with the progress bar.